# How to write this query in Sequelize And Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can not figure it out how to write this type of query in Sequelize.

`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (senderId=324 AND receiverId=340) OR (receiverId=324 AND senderId = 340) AND documentSetId=585;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
YourModel.findAll({
            where: {
                documentSetId: 585,
                $or: [
                    {
                        senderId: 324,
                        receiverId: 340,
                    }, {
                        senderId: 340,
                        receiverId: 324,
                    },
                ],
            },
        })
```